# PHPMailer: Parse error on the line 'composer install'

Tags: php, html, phpmailer, mail-server

I am trying to use PHPMailer on GoDaddy, this is my first time using it - however, it gives me the error; `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'install' (T_STRING)`; on the line `composer install`, what is wrong? I have looked around at other posts and played around with the code but I still cannot figure out what is wrong.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
 <?php

composer install
composer require phpmailer/phpmailer

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;  
    $mail->isSMTP();    
    $mail->Host       = 'stmp.gmail.com'; 
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;  
    $mail->Username   = 'MY EMAIL';  
    $mail->Password   = 'MY PASSWORD'; 
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;
    $mail->Port       = 465;  

    $mail->setFrom('MY EMAIL', 'MY NAME');

    $mail->addAddress('xxx'); 


    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the main message';
    $mail->AltBody = 'Some body text';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Comment: You need to start this command via CMD in your project's root folder.

It will generate a vendor folder, with the PHPMailler library, then you will be able to use it.

here something that can help you understand the composer.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6wm15OWyqg

The site composer> https://getcomposer.org/

Answer (score 0):

**note**: If you are using a shared hosting on go daddy and not a dedicated server, I think you will not be able to run the composer, you will only use the SMTP configuration

otherwise try this

Run the commands via the command line.

```
composer require phpmailer/phpmailer
```

A folder called vendor will appear in your directory

- root_path/

  - vendor/
  - index.php

Your php file should look like this

**index.php**

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;


$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;  
    $mail->isSMTP();    
    $mail->Host       = 'stmp.gmail.com'; 
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;  
    $mail->Username   = 'MY EMAIL';  
    $mail->Password   = 'MY PASSWORD'; 
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;
    $mail->Port       = 465;  

    $mail->setFrom('MY EMAIL', 'MY NAME');

    $mail->addAddress('xxx'); 


    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the main message';
    $mail->AltBody = 'Some body text';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! Do you know any tutorials or ways to do this through cpanel ?